# Fancybox 2 Show ajax result as iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

Ok so all the other questions either have to do with version 1 instead of version 2 or they are just calling a simple file with 1 variable. Essentially what I want to do is take the input fields and pass them to a PHP file withOUT submitting the form and displaying the html echo in a Fancybox.

On version 1.34 you used $.fancybox.showActivity. But that is not an option in version 2.

So I've tried the following:

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: "exec/preview.php",  
         data: $('#campaignform').serialize(),  
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(data){
            $.fancybox({
                               'content' : data,
                               'type' : 'iframe'
                            });
        }   
});
```

But I get The requested URL /[object Object] was not found on this server.

I've tried setting type to inline. all it does is act like its submitting the form. This is a PREVIEW before it actually publishes the campaign.

Changing the SUCCESS function to this:

```
success: function(data){
    $.fancybox(data,{
        'type' : 'iframe'
    });
}
```

Appends all the returned data in the URL of the iframe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fiddled around with this and it's tricky because there's no documentation whatsoever for FancyBox2.

I think this (ajax version) should work:

```
$("#your_form_id").submit(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        padding         : 0,
        autoSize        : true,
        minHeight       : 10,
        fitToView       : false,
        arrows          : false,
        href            : $(this).attr("action"), //Your form must have an action.
        type            : 'ajax',
        ajax            : {
                type    : "GET",
                cache   : false,
                data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
        },
        scrolling       : 'no',
        transitionIn    : 'none',
        transitionOut   : 'none'
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zeno. Only problem now is that when it loads the content, if I click the X to close (upper right corner), the close button disappears but the fancybox doesnt close. If I click outside the fancybox, it disappears but the screen stays dim. Any Ideas?

Comment: Sorry ... noticed it just now :( This should not happen. If you provide me with a test page, I could look into it.

Comment: Go to marketing.wdctravel.com and log in with support@worlddiscoveryclub.com and mc101005. Click campaigns and then new campaign. Step through campaign wizard and on last step press preview. That does an Ajax call into I frame but u can't close fancy box out

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fancybox. You're including 2 versions of jquery.easing plugins and probably you're not including the jquery.easing.compatibility.js from http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/. You also have included some duplicate scripts there.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you could also try not using the easing functions. Will do away with some of the fancy animations, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://fancybox.net/blog#tip5

Scroll down a bit and you will see the exact same thing you are tring to do in the simple validation example.

Comment: Please note I'm using Fancybox 2 not Fancybox 1

Comment: using the example at http://fancybox.net/blog/#tip5 causes the site to try to load more javascript and header information on the same page. It doesnt load it as an iframe in the fancybox. Forcing type to iframe causes the SRC of the iframe to have all the HTML appended to it.

Comment: This worked fine for me using FancyBox 2, specifically the last part of tip #5: "Simple validation; submit data using Ajax and display response"